# Install python packages through ap-get in Debian

Tags: debian, apt

I'm trying to install Odoo on a Debian 3.2, but I'm having trouble trying to install its dependencies.

When I try to install `python-decorator`, I get this error:

```
The python-decorator package is not available, but some other package references
him. This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only
is available from another source

E: The package "python-decorator 'has no installation candidate
```

And this is my sources.list:

```
deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 7.8.0 _Wheezy_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20150110-14:43]/ wheezy contrib main

deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main contrib
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main contrib
```

Comment: Debian 3.2? I assume you mean Debian 7 (Wheezy) with the 3.2 kernel?

Comment: yes, Debian 7, I got confused

Comment: What does the command "apt-cache policy python-decorator" output? Which sources do you have configured? The package is available in Wheezy: https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/python-decorator

Comment: python-decorator:
  Instalados: (ninguno)
  Candidato:  (ninguno)
  Tabla de versión:


It's a clean Wheezy instalation.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add your /etc/apt/sources.list and the listing in /etc/apt/sources.list.d (if any)? Looks like you do not have external resources configured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have configured external resources. You can check this by looking at /etc/apt/sources.list and possibly the files in /etc/apt/sources.list.d. A minimal /etc/apt/sources.list that allows you to install packages from the internet archives is:

```
deb     http://http.debian.org/debian/        wheezy  main
deb     http://security.debian.org/     wheezy/updates  main
deb     http://http.debian.org/debian/        wheezy-updates  main
```

Then run "sudo apt-get update" and you'll be able to "sudo apt-get install python-decorator".

Comment: Thank you! I found the solution at the same time. It's weird because I didn't edit my sources.plist

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. The problem was with the sources.list, which was looking just in the Debian DVD instead of the official Internet repository.

Using http://debgen.simplylinux.ch/ I generated a new sources.list and after that `apt-get update` to get it working. This is the sources.list I'm using:

```
deb http://ftp.es.debian.org/debian stable main contrib non-free

deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates main contrib non-free

deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main contrib non-free
```

Comment: Ah, our answers just crossed :)